# Javascript limiting json https result

Tags: javascript, json, firefox-addon, roblox

Basically I made a firefox extension that gets a list of ids from my website, and deletes them on [roblox.com](https://roblox.com)
but for some reason the list stops on "8563844698" and dosent read anything after.
this is the site where the list is at "https://nobadrblxgames.ct8.pl/"
and the extension is at https://addons.mozilla.org/en-CA/firefox/addon/no-showing-bad-roblox-games/
This is the js code.

```
var linkIDs = [];
fetch('https://nobadrblxgames.ct8.pl/index.html')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    var linkIDs = data.values;
    console.log(linkIDs);
    var loopthinglol = setInterval(function(){
      // Get elements with the class name
      var gameCardLinks = document.getElementsByClassName("game-card-link");
      
      // Iterate through the elements and check if the href contains any of the link IDs
      for (var i = 0; i < gameCardLinks.length; i++) {
        var href = gameCardLinks[i].getAttribute("href");
      
        // Check if the href contains any of the link IDs
        for (var j = 0; j < linkIDs.length; j++) {
          if (href.includes(linkIDs[j])) {
            var parent = gameCardLinks[i].parentNode.parentNode;
            var belowparent = gameCardLinks[i].parentNode;
            if (parent.classList.contains("list-item") &&
                parent.classList.contains("game-card") &&
                parent.classList.contains("game-tile")) {
              // Remove the parent of the parent element
              belowparent.removeChild(gameCardLinks[i]);
              console.log("Removed element:", gameCardLinks[i]);
            } else if (
              belowparent.hasAttribute("data-testid") &&
              belowparent.getAttribute("data-testid").includes("game-tile")
            ) {
              // Remove the parent element
              belowparent.removeChild(gameCardLinks[i]);
              console.log("Removed element:", gameCardLinks[i]);
            }
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      }, 1200);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  });
```

ive tried using Set() for the linkIDs table but didnt work

Comment: Can you show also your **html** data? I think there is something wrong with your code.

Comment: @Newbee as i just mentioned this code is for roblox.com/discover and the home page and searching for games.

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow (SO) (and all of Stack Exchange (SE)) *must be* self-contained. The goal of SO/SE is to create a repository of questions and answers which are valuable to *future* visitors. Questions which *require* information from off-site/off-page resources are useless once those resources change or die. Any questions where such a resource is *required* to understand the question should be closed as "needs details of clarity", or other appropriate reason. Only *information (e.g. code) **in the question itself*** is considered. A link can be used for context, but not relied upon.

Comment: <a class="game-card-link" href="https://www.roblox.com/games/12503835067/Blox-Fruits-2?gameSearchSessionInfo=24ec0095-44fc-498b-bf94-b80a8249f296&amp;isAd=false&amp;nativeAdData=&amp;numberOfLoadedTiles=40&amp;page=searchPage&amp;placeId=12503835067&amp;position=0&amp;universeId=4394213946" id="4394213946"></a>